# Thrust Static Assertion when using in cpp files

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, thrust

I am trying to compile and run a simple Cuda/thrust program, it works when the extension is `.cu` but it fails when the extension of source is `.cpp`.
I already applied the required changes for cpp file in cmake but I am getting

> error: static assertion failed: unimplemented for this system
>   THRUST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(thrust_test LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

find_package(CUDA 10.0 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "CUDA ${CUDA_VERSION_STRING} at ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}")
set(CUDA_LINK_LIBRARIES_KEYWORD PUBLIC)

include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${CUDA_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

set_source_files_properties(
        main.cpp
        PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SOURCE_PROPERTY_FORMAT
        OBJ)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

and the main.cpp:

```
__host__
__device__
int foo() {

    // generate random data serially
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(100);
    std::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);

    // transfer to device and compute sum
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;
    return thrust::reduce(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), 0, thrust::plus<int>());
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Thrust v" <<  THRUST_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << THRUST_MINOR_VERSION << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the CUDA first-class language support in cmake (which is what you're doing when you establish that `CUDA` is a language used by your project) means that cmake is going to use the NVidia compiler for `.cu` files and some other compiler (such as gcc) on other files. When you use `add_executable`, cmake is also checking for `.cu` file extensions to ascertain how to properly link together your application.

`FindCUDA` is an older set of tools that does not necessarily override these behaviors. You've gone 90% of the way toward replicating the first-class language features using the macros provided by `FindCUDA`, but `add_executable` fails to perform some necessary additional steps so your application bombs. Normally you'd use the `CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE` macro to designate a CUDA executable when using the `FindCUDA` tools.

So here's what you should do: if you don't want your main file to have a `.cu` extension then just move your `foo` function to a separate `.cu` file with its own header that you include in `main.cpp`. You won't need to use `set_source_files_properties` since your device code will be properly segregated into its own `.cu`, allowing cmake to take the proper steps.

Have a look at this article for more details and references:
https://shawnliu.me/post/cuda-as-a-language-in-cmake/

Comment: Thanks, Michael I studied the link you provided but unfortunately, your solution and comments did not help me get around this problem. This example is a simplified version of a project where there are functions that could be compiled for both CPU and GPU and because I want to prevent code duplication I want to keep all implementation of all in .cpp files and be able to compile with nvcc or gcc whenever I want. So I just want the cpp files to be compiled the same way as .cu files

Comment: @AMCoded You can use nvcc to compile thrust directives even if they're running against CPU-only targets. So you should always use nvcc to compile .cu files regardless, and then use defines to designate how you're calling your thrust functions